# Obtain volume help

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I get a pointer to VolumeDeviceObject?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563030(v=vs.85).aspx

```
NTSTATUS RtlVolumeDeviceToDosName(
  __in   PVOID VolumeDeviceObject,
  __out  PUNICODE_STRING DosName
);
```

VolumeDeviceObject [in]
Pointer to a device object that represents a volume device object created by a storage class driver.

Comment: I have a device path like \Device\HarddiskVolume2

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [IoGetDeviceObjectPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It returns a device object for the specified string.